# Why does deselecting specific DataGridViewRow also deselect all other rows?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I've got a Form with a DataGridView. Based on certain conditions, I programmatically deselect a single Row (by setting `Selected` to `false`). But when I do that, if another row was currently selected it is deselected also. I've set the DataGridView to `MultiSelect = false`. The user should only be able to select a single row.

It seems that setting any row's `Selected` property causes the control to see that as *selecting* the row, thereby deselecting any previously selected row. The fact that I'm setting the `Selected` property to `false` doesn't change that behavior. This only happens if  `MultiSelect` is set to `false` and `SelectionMode` is set to `FullRowSelect` though.

I can solve it by only setting the property if it's currently `true`.

```
if (row.Selected) row.Selected = false;
```

But I'd like to know why this happens. And why only when SelectionMode is set to FullRowSelect?

**Complete example**

The following sample code contains a complete working example. The constructor will add three rows. Clicking the button will deselect the middle row. But no matter which row was selected before clicking the button, the end result will be that no row is selected.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MainForm : Form
{
    static void Main() { Application.Run(new MainForm()); }

    private DataGridView _dataGridView;
    private Button _SelectButton;

    public MainForm()
    {
        _dataGridView = new DataGridView
        { ReadOnly = true, AllowUserToAddRows = false };
        _dataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        _dataGridView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        _dataGridView.MultiSelect = false;
        _dataGridView.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewColumn
        { CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell() });
        _dataGridView.Rows.Add("1");
        _dataGridView.Rows.Add("2");
        _dataGridView.Rows.Add("3");
        Controls.Add(_dataGridView);
        _SelectButton = new Button { Text = "Deselect middle row" };
        _SelectButton.Click += _SelectButton_Click;
        _SelectButton.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
        Controls.Add(_SelectButton);
    }

    void _SelectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _dataGridView.Rows[1].Selected = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree this is odd behavior. If you allow multi select, it works as expected, but when you don't allow multi select it seems to operate as if you called `_dataGridView.ClearSelection;`. The only solution I can see is to simply test if the row in question is selected before deselecting it.

```
void _SelectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_dataGridView.Rows[1].Selected)
    {
        _dataGridView.Rows[1].Selected = false;
    }            
}
```

Comment: I'v accepted your answer, although it doesn't explain why this happens. BUt I don't excpect any better answers to come.